# How to make LinearGAM().fit() function work?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, jupyter-lab, gam

I have a problem with a LinearGAM fit function. I use the below code to perform fit operation on the data I have in a DataFrame.

```
scaled = scaler.transform(data)
X2 = scaled[:,:-1]
y2 = scaled[:,-1]

gam2 = LinearGAM()
gam2.fit(X2, y2)
gam2.summary()
```

I tried using the StandardScaler and other transformations like for example PowerTransformer, and I still get a huge error that finishes with:
[Error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0ihx.png)

I tried to search for result in the Internet, but nothing works for me. Does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: What is your`numpy` version?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to use `LinearGAM().fit()` function:

```
import pygam
from pygam.datasets import wage
X, y = wage()
from pygam import LinearGAM, s, f
gam = LinearGAM(s(0) + s(1) + f(2)).fit(X, y)
```

Output

```
LinearGAM(callbacks=[Deviance(), Diffs()], fit_intercept=True, 
   max_iter=100, scale=None, terms=s(0) + s(1) + f(2) + intercept, 
   tol=0.0001, verbose=False)
```

https://pygam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/quick_start.html

You need to upgrade your `numpy >= 1.24` and

I am using :

```
pygam.__version__

'0.8.0'
```